# can't decrypt encrypted RSA data by OpenSSL

Tags: php, encryption

I generate public and private keys for RSA by

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

and use following php code to encrypt and decrypt data.

```
<?php
$plaintext = 'Hello';
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public('file://public.pem');
$encrypted = '';
if (!openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey))
    die('Failed to encrypt data');
var_dump($encrypted);


if (!$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://private.pem', '123456789'))
    die('Private Key failed');
$decrypted = '';
if (openssl_open($encrypted, $decrypted, $envelope, $privateKey) === FALSE)
    die('Failed to decrypt data');
?>
```

it will encrypt data ,but to decrypt data it doesn't work and show **Failed to decrypt data**

it will show some thing like following result

```
string(256) "y)ù¿5_÷q$çD±!‘­[’ÓcÜC$Gèïü*ÞEÇGm>ËÂïQÄ„ð­½i=é¨Zs€©   |T²»Z”k( ráëµ1,r]o  –Òll'T¾i¹Bò}Æ1sËèÝwœÒ„Ä–È‹\1{S'ÆY³Ïà^hŽ™©XO%f7‘Bþ®Ra.ªÜäÆô¼'©³#Ý.H9…ŒÏ\6°ÆýþÆJµ^ðŠØÆr£Ô&ü—Ý*ýÄq ƒÝcÓÚAçOmœi\Ê¿›ãB~ZP1ŒÑÔâ¨S…6—êQ–Â²x¥^0´Íº(d?G•ÚIWå¡Ä" Failed to decrypt data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [`openssl_public_encrypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) to encrypt your data, you need to use [`openssl_private_decrypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) to decrypt the data.

[`openssl_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-open.php) is for use with [`openssl_seal()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php).

I'd recommend using the `_open()` and `_seal()` variants instead of the `_public_encrypt()` and `_private_decrypt()` variants -- the public key mechanisms are intended solely for *session key transport* and *digital signatures*. Public-key algorithms are intended for use on random data (or nearly-random data of [message digests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)). Using non-random data with public key algorithms is definitely a mis-use of the algorithms.